# Why is this regexp not working?

Tags: python, regex

This is what I have and it's not working:

```
p = re.compile(r'foo/(?P<id>\d)/')
m = p.search('foo/234/')
```

Why is `m` `None`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use a quantifier `\d+` instead of `\d`, to match one or more digit:

```
re.compile(r'foo/(?P<id>\d+)/')
```